# Как реализован Google Calculator?

Tags: java, математика, точность

Делаю свой калькулятор, вроде написан, вроде всё работает, но смотрю на тот же Калькулятор у Google, как мне становится стрёмно, у меня точность вычислений ограничена в 17 знаков, у них - бесконечно, так как когда мы считаем у них например выражение "1/42245", то там можно пальцем мотать до конца, пока мантисса не кончится, вот я и ломаю голову и не понимаю, какой алгоритм они юзают, если знаете литературу, то скиньте пожалуйста, уже просто интересно, как можно такое придумать. :)

Comment: если чем-то поможет то их репозиторий https://github.com/microsoft/calculator

Comment: Unix утилиты bc/dc (только написаны на Си, а не java) проделывают это (неограниченная точность) еще года с 77-го.

Comment: Вы в расчётах тип `double` используете или `float`? У первого точность больше. Если её не достаточно - тогда [`BigDecimal`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/math/BigDecimal) вам в помощь - его точность технически ограничена только наличием свободной памяти и максимально возможным индексом массива `Integer.MAX_VALUE` для количества знаков.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/smartprogress/blog/322756/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Обычно для таких целей используются специализированные библиотеки для вычислений с неограниченной точностью.

Для Java, например, можно использовать [Java Algebra System](http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/) или [JScience](http://jscience.org/)